# Generics and Action Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates, action

I have the following code :

```
public void generate()
{
  base.generateFoo(Method); // How can i indicate the type here?
}

public void Method<T>(T t , IDictionary<T, SomeObject> coll) : where T : ISomething
{
 // do something
}


class MyBase
{
  public void generateFoo<T>(Action<T, IDictionary<T, SomeObject>> Method) : where T : ISomething
  {
     Method.invoke(ObjectThatImplementsT, DictionaryWIthTKey);
  }
}
```

I m getting an error like cannot convert ObjectThatImplementsT  to T.

Can i pass a generic method as a paramter to another method?

What s the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to specify the type:

```
public void generate()
{
   base.generateFoo<YourType>(Method);
}
```

That being said - the above code, as written, will not compile, since `generateFoo` is not a generic method nor in a generic class, so it's possible the above will not work.  It's assuming that `generateFoo` is defined as a generic method (taking type `T`).

Comment: I was just a smidge too slow :)

Comment: it s a generic method. sorry.

Comment: But I m getting : Variable can not be used as a Type Argument error.

Comment: within the base class. while im invoking the action.

Comment: Maybe a more realistic code sample is required; You would only get the error you specify if you were trying to explicitly specify the generic type when calling the delegate, using a named variable instead of a statically-defined type identifier.

Comment: Method<MyType>(var1, dict1); and it complains : The variable 'Method' can not be used with type arguments.

Comment: @user177883: You need to just specify "Method" (like above), not Method with other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `generateFoo` generic to T, with the same restrictions as Method. Your example actually won't compile otherwise, as T is unknown to MyBase (unless you actually have a class named T in a known namespace).

Answer (score 1):

All of the above applies, lots of minor edits (why don't you compile your sample yourself so we can know what 'problems' are bogus and what is really your question?!)

Here is a compiling bit - note three variations of calling generateFoo:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace X 
{ 
    class Y : MyBase
    {
        public static void Main(string[]args) { }

        public void generate()
        {
            base.generateFoo<Something>(Method<Something>); // works
            base.generateFoo<Something>(Method); // works as well
            base.generateFoo(Method<Something>); // doesn't (cannot be inferred)
        }

        public void Method<T>(T t , IDictionary<T, SomeObject> coll) 
            where T : ISomething
        {
            // do something
        }

    }

    class MyBase
    {
        public void generateFoo<T>(Action<T, IDictionary<T, SomeObject>> Method) 
            where T : class, ISomething
        {
            Method.Invoke((T) null, new Dictionary<T,SomeObject>());
        }
    }
    internal interface ISomething {}
    internal class Something : ISomething {}
    internal class SomeObject {}
}
```